# Android -> PC USB Communication

Tags: java, android, usb, adb

I'm something of a novice when it comes to Android apps, so bear with me. I would like to have communication between an app that I make, and a process on a computer. This could be using TCP, or with some USB-specific protocol. I was thinking I'd write the computer-side application in Java to allow for better cross-platform support.

The research I've done thus far has mentioned a concept of USB hosts, which seems like the sort of thing I need to use. The documentation for all of this has been a little unclear. Could someone please either give me a link to a clearer article, or explain an article? Thanks.

What I'm looking for is a way for a PC to send data to the android device. The device acts on that data, then sends it back to the PC.

Comment: what kind of USB communication do you want? Something to debug the app? or something a bit more "informational" to the devices? (like instructions to perform an action)

Comment: There's actually no real supported/official way to do this, but various workarounds have been discussed here many times before.  Try using the search box on the upper right.

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to a native Windows library, either.

Comment: It needs to be via USB cable?

Comment: you could send text files (with text in for example a JSON format) or an sqlite db via adb. Or have the computer detect the device and then send blutooth, wireless or some other connection protocol authentication over. Not sure why there isnt proper support for this yet. 

There might also be cool info in the SDK samples. There is a USB one which goes into a lot of detail

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Bluetooth would be fine, I guess. It's rather slow, but maybe that's just my impression.

Comment: @Alex, tell me more about this SQLLite DB via ADB. That sounds like the sort of thing I'd like :).